# Unity icons problem

Tags: unity, icons

Ever since I upgraded to 13.10 the icons in the Unity panel appears in Gnome's default theme instead of Unity.

Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpWZS.png

Both the unity tweak tool and the gnome tweak tools show that the selected icon theme is Ubuntu-mono-dark.

Executing `setsid unity` fixes the icons for the current session, but after logging in again the icons go back to the Gnome default theme.

Answer (score 0):

If memory doesn't fails me, the name of the Icon theme isn't Ubuntu-mono-dark but Humanity.

Comment: I do have an icon theme named humanity, but switching to it doesn't seem to resolve the problem